# Graphviz ignore edge when deciding layout

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have an edge in a dot graph that I need to be ignored by other edges during the layout. I have tried feeding the first part of the code through `dot` and then adding dotted edges below, however the other solid edges still keep being affected by them.

The code:

```
digraph structs {
    rankdir=LR
    edge [tailclip=false];
    node [shape=record];
    header [label="{<0> |<1> header|<2>  }"];
    data0 [label="{<0> |<1> data0|<2> }"];
    data1 [label="{<0> |<1> data1|<2> }"];
    trailer [label="{<0> |<1> trailer|<2> }"];

    header -> data0 -> data1 -> trailer [style=invis, weight=100];
    edge [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, weight=40];
    header:2:c -> data0:1:n;
    data0:0:c -> header:1:s;


    data0:2:c -> data1:1:n;
    data1:0:c -> data0:1:s;

    data1:2:c -> trailer:1:n ;
    trailer:0:c -> data1:1:s;

    edge [constraint=false, style=dashed, weight=0, layer=1];
    data0:2:c -> trailer:1:n [weight=0];
    trailer:0:c -> data0:1:s [weight=0];

}
```

The results:
[image: The result]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your question. Can you give an explanation of what goes wrong (maybe also an image of the situation "before" and the wanted situation).

Comment: This is exactly my question. I want to draw certain edges while the layout algorithm should ignore them when positioning the nodes. I know dot can do this but I don't know how to look it up in the documentation.